RL: Why are the rewards in reward normalisation discounted in the "opposite direction" (backwards) in RND
In Random Network Distillation the rewards are normalised because of the presence of intrinsic and extrinsic rewards. However, in the CleanRL implementation the rewards used to calculate the standard deviation which itself is used to normalise the rewards are not discounted as usual. From what I see, the discounting is done in the opposite direction of what is usually done, where we want to have rewards far in the future stronger discounted than rewards closer to the present. For context, gymnasium provides a NormalizeReward wrapper where the rewards are also discounted in the "opposite direction".
Below you can see that in the CleanRL implementation of RND the rewards are passed in normal order (i.e., not from the last step in time to the first step in time).
curiosity_reward_per_env = np.array([discounted_reward.update(reward_per_step) for reward_per_step in curiosity_rewards.cpu().data.numpy().T])
mean, std, count = (np.mean(curiosity_reward_per_env), np.std(curiosity_reward_per_env), len(curiosity_reward_per_env),)
reward_rms.update_from_moments(mean, std**2, count)

curiosity_rewards /= np.sqrt(reward_rms.var)

And below you can see the class responsible for calculating the discounted rewards that are then used to calculate the standard deviation for reward normalisation in CleanRL.
class RewardForwardFilter:
    def __init__(self, gamma):
        self.rewems = None
        self.gamma = gamma

    def update(self, rews):
        if self.rewems is None:
            self.rewems = rews
        else:
            self.rewems = self.rewems * self.gamma + rews
        return self.rewems

On GitHub one of the authors of the RND papers states "One caveat is that for convenience we do the discounting backwards in time rather than forwards (it's convenient because at any moment the past is fully available and the future is yet to come)."
My question is why can we use the standard deviation of the rewards that were discounted in the "opposite direction" (backwards) to normalise the rewards that are (or will be) discounted forwards (i.e., we want that the same reward in the future is worth less than the same reward in the present).

Hi @jonupp and welcome to AI Stack Exchange. This is one of the best questions from a new poster in terms of quality that I've ever seen. Thank you so much for posting, and we hope to see more of your questions here soon!
